# Daily/Weekly/Monthly Active Users on Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am creating a dashboard to show both Monthly Active Users and Weekly Active Users from Google Analytics.

To query this data I am using the following parameters:

```
{
  "ids" => @account_id,
  "start-date" => start_date.to_s,
  "end-date" => end_date.to_s,
  "metrics"=> "ga:users",
  "samplingLevel" => "HIGHER_PRECISION"
}
```

For example, to get Weekly Active Users for each day I'm passing a 7 day interval and for Monthly Active Users I'm using 30 day interval.

The point is that numbers are significantly different comparing to what I've seen in the interface at *Audience > Active Users*.

I couldn't figure out a query to get the same data from the interface. Do you have any idea?

thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think they're currently documented, but you can actually use the following metrics in your API requests:

- `ga:1dayUsers`
- `ga:7dayUsers`
- `ga:14dayUsers`
- `ga:30dayUsers`

Note that `ga:1dayUsers` and `ga:users` are essentially the same thing, but `ga:users` and any of the active users metrics cannot be combined in the same request, so if you want to compare you should use `ga:1dayUsers`.

**Update**

Queries that use any of the active users metrics mentioned above must be combined with a day dimension (e.g. `ga:date`) in order to work.

Comment: Thanks! Can you just confirm the right way to use this metrics? I am receiving 400 Bad Request with the following parameters: `{"ids"=> @account_id, "start-date"=>"2015-08-19", "end-date"=>"2015-08-25", "metrics"=>"ga:7dayUsers"}`

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I think the active users metrics require a date dimension. Try this: `{"ids"=> @account_id, "start-date"=>"2015-08-19", "end-date"=>"2015-08-25", "metrics"=>"ga:7dayUsers", "dimensions"=>"ga:date"}`.

Comment: Wow, I thought it was just impossible to do and Google returns only this link for "ga:7dayUsers". Thank you!

Comment: This is an old as post, but is still the only thing I can find with this solution. Are you able to use dimensions other than ga:date with ga:7dayUsers, such as deviceCategory, or does it have to be strictly ga:date only?

Comment: @tomb I think you'd probably want to use a segment for that since you're not trying to eliminate rows from the results, you're trying to eliminate users.

Comment: @PhilipWalton thanks a bunch! I read about these metrics someplace else too but they didn't mention the dimension ga:date as required.

Comment: @PhilipWalton Is there any metric for hourly users? in v4

Answer (score 1):

The following code should be able to help you collect this data in a single dataframe.

Please note that more than 1 type of variable cannot be captured in the query i.e. at a time, only one of the 1/7/14/28/30 day users can be queried.

At any given point in this on a particular date, the data will be rolled up i.e. If you observe 14 day User data on say 15th of the month then it will be unique users from 1st to 14th. for 16th this will be from 2nd to 15th and so on.

Hope this helps. R Code:

```
unique_1dayUser_data<-google_analytics(ga_id_raw,date_range=c(start_date,end_date),metrics=c("1dayUsers"),dimensions=c("date"))
unique_7dayUser_data<-google_analytics(ga_id_raw,date_range=c(start_date,end_date),metrics=c("7dayUsers"),dimensions=c("date"))
unique_14dayUser_data<-google_analytics(ga_id_raw,date_range=c(start_date,end_date),metrics=c("14dayUsers"),dimensions=c("date"))
unique_28dayUser_data<-google_analytics(ga_id_raw,date_range=c(start_date,end_date),metrics=c("28dayUsers"),dimensions=c("date"))
unique_30dayUser_data<-google_analytics(ga_id_raw,date_range=c(start_date,end_date),metrics=c("30dayUsers"),dimensions=c("date"))

unique_user_data<-cbind(unique_1dayUser_data,unique_7dayUser_data$`7dayUsers`,unique_14dayUser_data$`14dayUsers`,
                        unique_28dayUser_data$`28dayUsers`,unique_30dayUser_data$`30dayUsers`)

colnames(unique_user_data)<-c("Date","1 Day users","7 Day users","14 Day users","28 Day users","30 Day users")
```